# Why some Haskell functions does not abstract concrete integral type?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

For example, function `length` abstracts concrete sequence (`Foldable`), but do not abstract concrete integral type `Int`:

```
length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int
```

Would it be more useable or more convenient to have following type signature?

```
length' :: Foldable t, Integral i => t a -> i
```

Comment: As a hunch, it's because `Foldable`s with "length" greater than `2^29 - 1` are sufficiently rare (and time-consuming to compute) that anyone needing it wouldn't mind writing a quick `length' = foldl' (\a _ -> a+1) 0` instead.

Comment: Note that genericLength does exist.

Comment: @Alec However it's only defined for `List`, rather than all `Foldable`s ([hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=genericLength)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, perhaps, however first take note that more polymorphism is not always a good thing. If all functions have highly polymorphic arguments *and* results, then the compiler has little information to start type inference, so you end up having to type more awkward local signatures.

Now as for `length`, there is very little reason why it you'd want a result of any other `Integral` type but `Int`, at least not on a 64-bit machine:

- Smaller types like `Word16` don't usually give much performance- or memory advantage in Haskell, because there'll be some boxing somwhere, and then you have a 64-bit pointer to only 16 bits of information... bit silly.
- It's basically impossible to have a list (let alone array or map) so large that its length can't be measured with a 63 bit word. Even for a crazy lazy list that never completely exists in memory at any time.
  Now, strictly speaking, `Int` only guarantees 29 which can in some extreme cases be exhausted, but practically this is only relevant on 32-bit platforms which are anyways more limited in memory and performance, so you wouldn't want to juggle such huge data.
- For that matter, any application where performance *or* exhaustion could possibly an issue should probably be optimised to something more efficient than lists or other `Foldable` (which are always boxed due to parametricity); unboxed vectors or `ByteString`s perform much better.
- If you need the result to be `Integer` or something else more expensive, not for length but simply context reasons, it is probably a better idea to just calculate the length in `Int` and convert once *at the end*, rather than dragging around a slow addition through the entire list.

That said, I do in fact sometimes wish the signature was in fact that of the [actually existing](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericLength)

```
genericlength :: (Foldable t, Num i) => t a -> i
```

...note that the function doesn't need to *know* its result will be integral. And in fact it would often be pretty useful to make the result *rational*, so we could then just write

```
average :: Fractional n => [n] -> n
average l = sum l / length l
```

instead of needing an extra `fromIntegral`.

The reason this isn't the case in `Prelude.length`? I don't know, seems rather historical. The rationale is probably as I said in the beginning that you don't want *too much polymorphism*. Then again, IMO it's usually a good idea to make function *results* as polymorphic as possible, and rather constrain the *arguments* a bit more tightly, because then the result will always be bound to something that can be used for type inference.

Comment: `genericLength` is sadly defined only for lists, not for `Foldable`s ([hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=genericLength)).

Comment: @hnefatl If you really want, you can define your own `genericLength` for `Foldable`.

Comment: @Shersh I'm aware, I've already given an implementation in my comment on the OP's question. My point is that the type of `genericLength` stated in this answer is not the same as the standard Prelude one which is linked to, which has type `Num i => [a] -> i`.